# Spinning wheel in javascript with trigger keystroke

Tags: javascript, html

I need a simple help about implement a keystroke event on this code.
so that the spinning wheel starts on a keystroke event like the spacebar.

How can i do that?
I have this code here and found a event code for the keystroke in javascript.

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        //your code
    }
}
```

is there anyone that is good in javascript and can implement this in the code below?

```js
var padding = {top:20, right:40, bottom:0, left:0},
            w = 500 - padding.left - padding.right,
            h = 500 - padding.top  - padding.bottom,
            r = Math.min(w, h)/2,
            rotation = 0,
            oldrotation = 0,
            picked = 100000,
            oldpick = [],
            color = d3.scale.category20();//category20c()
            //randomNumbers = getRandomNumbers();
        //http://osric.com/bingo-card-generator/?title=HTML+and+CSS+BINGO!&words=padding%2Cfont-family%2Ccolor%2Cfont-weight%2Cfont-size%2Cbackground-color%2Cnesting%2Cbottom%2Csans-serif%2Cperiod%2Cpound+sign%2C%EF%B9%A4body%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4ul%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4h1%EF%B9%A5%2Cmargin%2C%3C++%3E%2C{+}%2C%EF%B9%A4p%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4!DOCTYPE+html%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4head%EF%B9%A5%2Ccolon%2C%EF%B9%A4style%EF%B9%A5%2C.html%2CHTML%2CCSS%2CJavaScript%2Cborder&freespace=true&freespaceValue=Web+Design+Master&freespaceRandom=false&width=5&height=5&number=35#results
        var data = [
                    {"label":"Dell LAPTOP",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area between the content and its border?"}, // padding
                    {"label":"IMAC PRO",  "value":2,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the font?"}, //font-family
                    {"label":"SUZUKI",  "value":3,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the color of text?"}, //color
                    {"label":"HONDA",  "value":4,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the boldness of text?"}, //font-weight
                    {"label":"FERRARI",  "value":5,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the size of text?"}, //font-size
                    {"label":"APARTMENT",  "value":6,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the background color of a box?"}, //background-color
                    {"label":"IPAD PRO",  "value":7,  "question":"Which word is used for specifying an HTML tag that is inside another tag?"}, //nesting
                    {"label":"LAND",  "value":8,  "question":"Which side of the box is the third number in: margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; ?"}, //bottom
                    {"label":"MOTOROLLA",  "value":9,  "question":"What are the fonts that don't have serifs at the ends of letters called?"}, //sans-serif
                    {"label":"BMW", "value":10, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify a class?"}
        ];
        var svg = d3.select('#chart')
            .append("svg")
            .data([data])
            .attr("width",  w + padding.left + padding.right)
            .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);
        var container = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "chartholder")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2 + padding.left) + "," + (h/2 + padding.top) + ")");
        var vis = container
            .append("g");
            
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d){return 1;});
        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);
        // select paths, use arc generator to draw
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "slice");
            
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i){ return color(i); })
            .attr("d", function (d) { return arc(d); });
        // add the text
        arcs.append("text").attr("transform", function(d){
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = r;
                d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle)/2;
                return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.outerRadius -10) +")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text( function(d, i) {
                return data[i].label;
            });
        container.on("click", spin);
        function spin(d){
            
            container.on("click", null);
            //all slices have been seen, all done
            console.log("OldPick: " + oldpick.length, "Data length: " + data.length);
            if(oldpick.length == data.length){
                console.log("done");
                container.on("click", null);
                return;
            }
            var  ps       = 360/data.length,
                 pieslice = Math.round(1440/data.length),
                 rng      = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);
                
            rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);
            
            picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360)/ps);
            picked = picked >= data.length ? (picked % data.length) : picked;
            if(oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1){
                d3.select(this).call(spin);
                return;
            } else {
                oldpick.push(picked);
            }
            rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);
            vis.transition()
                .duration(3000)
                .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
                .each("end", function(){
                    //mark question as seen
                    d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
                        .attr("fill", "#111");
                    //populate question
                    d3.select("#question h1")
                        .text(data[picked].question);
                    oldrotation = rotation;
              
                    /* Get the result value from object "data" */
                    console.log(data[picked].value)
              
                    /* Comment the below line for restrict spin to sngle time */
                    container.on("click", spin);
                });
        }
        //make arrow
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + padding.left + padding.right) + "," + ((h/2)+padding.top) + ")")
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M-" + (r*.15) + ",0L0," + (r*.05) + "L0,-" + (r*.05) + "Z")
            .style({"fill":"black"});
        //draw spin circle
        container.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", 0)
            .attr("r", 60)
            .style({"fill":"white","cursor":"pointer"});
        //spin text
        container.append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("SPIN")
            .style({"font-weight":"bold", "font-size":"30px"});
        
        
        function rotTween(to) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
          return function(t) {
            return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
          };
        }
        
        
        function getRandomNumbers(){
            var array = new Uint16Array(1000);
            var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([360, 1440]).domain([0, 100000]);
            if(window.hasOwnProperty("crypto") && typeof window.crypto.getRandomValues === "function"){
                window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
                console.log("works");
            } else {
                //no support for crypto, get crappy random numbers
                for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++){
                    array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
                }
            }
            return array;
        }
```

```css
text{
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        pointer-events:none;
    }
    #chart{
        position:absolute;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    #question{
        position: absolute;
        width:400px;
        height:500px;
        top:0;
        left:520px;
    }
    #question h1{
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
                transform:translate(0,-50%);
    }
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="question"><h1></h1></div>
    
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, in your code, you need to call `spin()` function on key stroke and ***remove*** the `click` handler for spin `container.on("click", spin); // remove or comment`

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 32){
                spin()
            }
        }
```

---

Working Code below

```js
var padding = {
    top: 20,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  w = 500 - padding.left - padding.right,
  h = 500 - padding.top - padding.bottom,
  r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
  rotation = 0,
  oldrotation = 0,
  picked = 100000,
  oldpick = [],
  color = d3.scale.category20(); //category20c()
//randomNumbers = getRandomNumbers();
//http://osric.com/bingo-card-generator/?title=HTML+and+CSS+BINGO!&words=padding%2Cfont-family%2Ccolor%2Cfont-weight%2Cfont-size%2Cbackground-color%2Cnesting%2Cbottom%2Csans-serif%2Cperiod%2Cpound+sign%2C%EF%B9%A4body%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4ul%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4h1%EF%B9%A5%2Cmargin%2C%3C++%3E%2C{+}%2C%EF%B9%A4p%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4!DOCTYPE+html%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4head%EF%B9%A5%2Ccolon%2C%EF%B9%A4style%EF%B9%A5%2C.html%2CHTML%2CCSS%2CJavaScript%2Cborder&freespace=true&freespaceValue=Web+Design+Master&freespaceRandom=false&width=5&height=5&number=35#results
var data = [{
    "label": "Dell LAPTOP",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for specifying the area between the content and its border?"
  }, // padding
  {
    "label": "IMAC PRO",
    "value": 2,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the font?"
  }, //font-family
  {
    "label": "SUZUKI",
    "value": 3,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the color of text?"
  }, //color
  {
    "label": "HONDA",
    "value": 4,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the boldness of text?"
  }, //font-weight
  {
    "label": "FERRARI",
    "value": 5,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the size of text?"
  }, //font-size
  {
    "label": "APARTMENT",
    "value": 6,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the background color of a box?"
  }, //background-color
  {
    "label": "IPAD PRO",
    "value": 7,
    "question": "Which word is used for specifying an HTML tag that is inside another tag?"
  }, //nesting
  {
    "label": "LAND",
    "value": 8,
    "question": "Which side of the box is the third number in: margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; ?"
  }, //bottom
  {
    "label": "MOTOROLLA",
    "value": 9,
    "question": "What are the fonts that don't have serifs at the ends of letters called?"
  }, //sans-serif
  {
    "label": "BMW",
    "value": 10,
    "question": "With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify a class?"
  }
];
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
  .append("svg")
  .data([data])
  .attr("width", w + padding.left + padding.right)
  .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);
var container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "chartholder")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2 + padding.left) + "," + (h / 2 + padding.top) + ")");
var vis = container
  .append("g");

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
  return 1;
});
// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);
// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(pie)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "slice");

arcs.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return arc(d);
  });
// add the text
arcs.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
    d.innerRadius = 0;
    d.outerRadius = r;
    d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.outerRadius - 10) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return data[i].label;
  });
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    spin()
  }
}

function spin(d) {

  container.on("click", null);

  //all slices have been seen, all done
  console.log("OldPick: " + oldpick.length, "Data length: " + data.length);
  if (oldpick.length == data.length) {
    console.log("done");
    container.on("click", null);
    return;
  }
  var ps = 360 / data.length,
    pieslice = Math.round(1440 / data.length),
    rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);

  rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);

  picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360) / ps);
  picked = picked >= data.length ? (picked % data.length) : picked;
  if (oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1) {
    d3.select(this).call(spin);
    return;
  } else {
    oldpick.push(picked);
  }
  rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps / 2);
  vis.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
    .each("end", function() {
      //mark question as seen
      d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
        .attr("fill", "#111");
      //populate question
      d3.select("#question h1")
        .text(data[picked].question);
      oldrotation = rotation;

      /* Get the result value from object "data" */
      console.log(data[picked].value)

      /* Comment the below line for restrict spin to sngle time */
      //container.on("click", spin);
    });
}
//make arrow
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + padding.left + padding.right) + "," + ((h / 2) + padding.top) + ")")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M-" + (r * .15) + ",0L0," + (r * .05) + "L0,-" + (r * .05) + "Z")
  .style({
    "fill": "black"
  });
//draw spin circle
container.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("r", 60)
  .style({
    "fill": "white",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  });
//spin text
container.append("text")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("SPIN")
  .style({
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "font-size": "30px"
  });


function rotTween(to) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
  return function(t) {
    return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
  };
}


function getRandomNumbers() {
  var array = new Uint16Array(1000);
  var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([360, 1440]).domain([0, 100000]);
  if (window.hasOwnProperty("crypto") && typeof window.crypto.getRandomValues === "function") {
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
    console.log("works");
  } else {
    //no support for crypto, get crappy random numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

```css
text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#chart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#question {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 520px;
}

#question h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="question">
  <h1></h1>
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: The spin click is isn't working I think.....

Comment: It works on pressing spacebar, which is what OP wanted. If you want to enable click, just uncomment or add `container.on("click", spin);`